# mobile website scrolling

Tags: html, mobile, scroll, smooth-scrolling

When scrolling down the page on my mobile website the content disappears and displays small grey and white squares. Once you stop scrolling the content reappears.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

My code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>PHP Test</title>
      <!-- Code within Head Tag -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(window).load(function(){
              $("#loading").hide();     
          })
      </script>
      <!-- Code within Head Tag -->

      <style type="text/css">
          /* Document Styles */

          #wrapper{
              width:800px;
              height:500px;
              margin:0 auto;
              padding:5px;
              border:1px solid #CCC;
              background:#CCC;
          }
          .desc{
              margin:5 auto;
              width:800px;
              text-align:left;
          }

          /* Loading Div Style */
          #loading{
              position:absolute;
              width:300px;
              top:0px;
              left:0%;
              margin-left:5px;
              text-align:left;
              padding:7px 0 0 0;
              font:bold 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          }
          body {
              overflow: hidden
          }
      </style>
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
   </head>
   <body>
       <center>
           <form>
               <!-- Loading Div -->
               <div id="loading">
                   Fetching Hotels, please wait..
                   <img src="loading.gif" alt="loading.." />
               </div>
               <!-- Loading Div -->
               <br>
               <input type=text value="destination" name=title onclick="this.value = '';"><br>
               Date:<br>
               <select name="month">
                   <option value="1">January
                   <option value="2">February
                   <option value="3">March
                   <option value="4">April
                   <option value="5">May
                   <option value="6">June
                   <option value="7">July
                   <option value="8">August
                   <option value="9">September
                   <option value="10">October
                   <option value="11">November
                   <option value="12">December
               </select>
               <select name="day">
                   <option value="1">1
                   <option value="2">2
                   <option value="3">3
                   <option value="4">4
                   <option value="5">5
                   <option value="6">6
                   <option value="7">7
                   <option value="8">8
                   <option value="9">9
                   <option value="10">10
                   <option value="11">11
                   <option value="12">12
                   <option value="13">13
                   <option value="14">14
                   <option value="15">15
                   <option value="16">16
                   <option value="17">17
                   <option value="18">18
                   <option value="19">19
                   <option value="20">20
                   <option value="21">21
                   <option value="22">22
                   <option value="23">23
                   <option value="24">24
                   <option value="25">25
                   <option value="26">26
                   <option value="27">27
                   <option value="28">28
                   <option value="29">29
                   <option value="30">30
                   <option value="31">31
               </select>
               <select name="year">
                   <option value="2012">2012
                   <option value="2013">2013
                   <option value="2014">2014
               </select>
               <br><br>
               No. of Nights:
               <select name="nights">
                   <option value="1">1
                   <option value="2">2
                   <option value="3">3
                   <option value="4">4
                   <option value="5">5
                   <option value="6">6
                   <option value="7">7
                   <option value="8">8
                   <option value="9">9
                   <option value="10">10
                   <option value="11">11
                   <option value="12">12
                   <option value="13">13
                   <option value="14">14
                   <option value="15">15
                   <option value="16">16
                   <option value="17">17
                   <option value="18">18 
               </select>

               <input type=submit>

               <?php
                   // specify url of xml file
                   $url = "http://xmlfeed.laterooms.com/index.aspx?aid=1000&rtype=4&kword=".$_GET['title']."&sdate=".$_GET['year']."-".$_GET['month']."-".$_GET['day']."&nights=".$_GET['nights']."&orderby=hoteldistance&sortorder=asc";
                   // get xml file contents
                   $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

                   // loop begins
                   $i = 0;
                   foreach($xml->hotel as $hotel)
                   {
                       if (++$i > 20) {
                           // stop after 5 loops
                           break;
                       }
                       // begin new paragraph
                       echo "<p>";
                       echo "<img src=".$hotel->images." height=100 width=100><br/>";
                       echo "<strong>Hotel Name:</strong> ".$hotel->hotel_name."<br/>";
                       echo "<strong>Prices From:</strong> &pound;".$hotel->prices_from."<br/>";
                       echo "<a href=".$hotel->hotel_link."><img src=http://affiliates.laterooms.com/AffiliateImages/en/buttons/more_details1.gif></a><br/>";
                       echo "<strong>Miles from ".$_GET['title']."</strong> ".$hotel->hotel_distance."<br/>";
                       echo "</p>";
                       // end paragraph
                   }
                   $cnt++;
                   // loop ends    
               ?>    
           </form> 
       </center>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't prevent this. (there might be a workaround tough)

I think this is how the browser, and the rendering works. Only the visible parts of the page are rendered, and if you scroll the page it has to render the new visible area. Until that it shows the checkerboard. However to save resources and for performance reasons (to avoid choppy scrolling) rendering happens only when you stop the scrolling.

So the workaround part:

If you create your own scrolling mechanism you can achieve what you want, but there are a few downsides. It might be slow, it is possible that this could cause incompatibility on some mobile browsers, etc.

The basic idea is that you place your content in a "fullscreen" div with overflow: hidden, and use javascript to catch (and override) the touchstart, touchend, touchmove, touchcancel events, and scroll the contents of the div by yourself, display your own scrollbar, etc. It is not too complicated, but there are a lot of things to do if you want to do it "right" with the bounce and overscroll, and everything. See iscroll4, it can do that for you :)